# Convert C++ Union Struct to VB6

Tags: c++, vb6, struct, unions

I have this struct in my C++ app:

```
struct textField
{
        //0
        union nameField
        {
                void* ptr;
                char cstring[16];
        } text;
        //16
        uint8_t textLength;
        //17
        char unknown1[3];
        //20
        uint8_t fieldType;
        //21
        char unknown2[3];
        //24
        uint32_t unknown3;
        //28
};
```

And I know that in VB6, it will look something like this:

```
Private Type textField        ' 0
    cstring(0 To 15) As Byte  ' 16
    textLength       As Byte  ' 17
    unknown1(0 To 2) As Byte  ' 20
    fieldType        As Byte  ' 21
    unknown2(0 To 2) As Byte  ' 24
    unknown3         As Long  ' 28
End Type
```

But what about the union in the struct? How can it be accomplished?

Comment: Incidentally, I would not use VB6 for **any** new projects. And any old projects that absolutely need to be maintained should probably be refactored into COM components which are then interacted with via .NET so that new code can be written in a modern language. As far as Microsoft is concerned, VB6 is dead.

Comment: @konrad I am aware of that, however I have this app in VB6 that needs a small update so it's not a new project.

Comment: Are you reading this structure as a piece of memory or implementing the same functionality?

Comment: @MatheusHenrique Ah okay then, carry on. I’m just mentioning it whenever somebody uses VB6 because there’s a frighteningly large number of people who don’t seem to have got the memo.

Comment: @mark I am reading this struct as a piece of memory I guess. The same functionality will have to be implemented in my VB6 app. This is the whole 1,6kb working C++ code: http://pastebin.com/AXLGhtwF

Comment: If there is that much C++ whey not call it from VB?

Comment: @mark I have thought about that, but I will stick to VB6 only. Btw, it doesn't have to print to a console like it's done in this C++ code. A MsgBox() can be used instead for displaying Data1 and Data2.

Comment: Looking for something similar, but looking like VB can't do it so easily. For this particular problem, and others like it, I would say just treat the string as packed binary data when you need to access it as a pointer. It's not the same as a union and you have to take extra steps to pack/unpack it, but I'm not seeing any other way with VB.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use the variant type - this can contain any other type.

Note that there probably is no direct mapping of `void *` into VB so you will need to study how the union is used rather than just a quick conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`LSET`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266163%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) command.

It's not declared in line with the struct, but rather thereafter upon declaring an instance of the object.

[Example](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/14418):

```
Private Type MyType1
    x as Integer
    y as Integer
    z as Integer
    w as Integer
End Type

Private Type MyType2
    a as Long
    b as Long
End Type

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim t1 as MyType1
    Dim t2 as MyType2
    t1.x = 0
    t1.y = 0
    t1.z = -1
    t1.w = -1

    LSet t2 = t1
    ....
```

This has the same effect as an unnamed union between the two types.

Comment: I didn't know this `LSET` command. I found this, heed the warning! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266163(v=vs.60).aspx. If I understand it well the four 16-bit integers are stored in two 32-bit ones using this method. Scary...

Comment: ugh.. stupid editor.. This is not correct, and has some potential problems, depending on how it's used. In C/C++, a union is more like telling the compiler that the memory region occupied by the union has more than one symbol (variable name) *and* data type. Using LSet does NOT assign the other variable to the same memory space; It merely COPIES the data from one variable in to the other, more like memcpy in C/C++. For some uses, this will work fine, but for others, it won't--you need to access the original, not a copy.